# VSTS REST API Caching

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm doing a lot of release definition requests and noticed that vsts does not provide an ETag so every request returns full json. Is this somehow configurable?

Sample request:

> https://{accountName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=4.1-preview.3

Comment: If you are looking for something just for release definitions, there is a revision property which is bumped up whenever anything changes in the definition. That might help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to configure this. Currently, only [the API for Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) supports ETag. Other API does not support it. I help you submitted an user voice here: [Support ETag for Rest API to improve the performance](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/35256553-support-etag-for-rest-api-to-improve-the-performan), you can vote on it.